# Как печатать каждый n-ый элемент массива в ruby?

Tags: ruby

Как печатать каждый n-ый элемент массива в ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = 3

for i in (n-1..arr.length - 1).step(n)
    puts arr[i]
end
```

Или же так:

```
(n-1..arr.length - 1).step(n) do |i|
    puts arr[i]
end
```

Или ещё компактнее:

```
(n-1..arr.length - 1).step(n) { |i| puts arr[i] }
```

Вывод:

```
3
6
```

Answer (score 5):

Например так:

```
 n = 5
 (1..40).step(n) {|y| puts y}
```

Будет печатать каждый 5-й элемент, начиная с 1-го.

Answer (score 4):

#### В функциональном стиле...

Возьму вот эти данные для примера:

```
a = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
n = 2 # каждый 2-й
```

```
(n-1...a.length).step(n)
                .map(&a.method(:[]))
                .each(&method(:puts))
# 9
# 7
# 5
# 3
# 1
```

- `n-1...a.length` это интересующий нас диапазон индексов, первый из которых обозначает первый элемент интересующего нас результата. Заметьте, что **точек три**, а значит указанная **правая граница в него не входит**. В конце концов, `a[a.length]` всегда `nil`.
- `(n-1...a.length).step(n)` пропускает все индексы из диапазона, кроме каждого `n`-го. Остаются только те, что нужны. Осталось найти способ преобразовать коллекцию индексов в коллекцию элементов.
- Есть у рубистов известный трюк с `Symbol#to_proc`: если всё, что должен делать блок, это вызвать у переданного в него объекта какой-то `метод`, то вместо написания этого блока руками можно передать в аргументы `&:метод` в качестве блока.

  ```
  (1..2).map { |i| i.to_s }
  (1..2).map(&:to_s) # <= то же самое
  ```

  Но здесь этот трюк не работает, поскольку метод надо вызвать не у переданного объекта. Нужен другой трюк. Чуть менее известный.

  Тут-то и можно воспользоваться `method`'ом: он возвращает `Proc`-совместимые объекты методов, всё ещё привязанных к своим владельцам. Амперсанд (&) при вызове метода работает со всем, что имеет метод `to_proc`).

  С помощью `.map(&a.method(:[]))` коллекция индексов преобразуется в коллекцию значений из `a` по этим индексам. А с помощью `.each(&method(:puts))` эта коллекция выводится на экран.

На самом деле, **решение совершенно непрактичное**, но показывает не самые известные детали языка.

Answer (score 3):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_with_index {|val, index| puts val if index % 2 == 0}
```